# How to add records to an Ecto Repository through Terminal? (iex)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've got a post model in my Phoenix Framework application.

I'd like to add records through my terminal. In Rails I can do something like this in the rails console:

```
u = Post.create title: "My Title", content: "Here's my content..."
```

What is the equivalent to this in IEX?

Answer (score 10):

first of all, you need to start your elixir terminal with

```
iex -S mix
```

make you have that `-S mix` or not it won't do.

after iex run, you just need to alias your module (to make it easier to access)

```
alias MyApp.Repo
alias MyApp.Post
```

after you setup the alias, you are ready to do anything you want. just test it with getting all the post with:

```
Repo.all(Post)
```

if there is no error (UndefinedFunctionError)
then you can just insert your data with:

```
Repo.insert(%Post{title: "My Title", content: "Here's my content..."})
```

hope it will help you. :D

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer in the [Phoenix Documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/ecto.html).

In IEx I can do this:

```
post = %MyApp.Post{title: "My Title", content: "Here's my content..."}
```

Followed by:

```
MyApp.Repo.insert post
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to start phoenix iex with:

```
iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

And then do a query to Ecto:

```
post = %MyApp.Post{title: "My Title", content: "Here's my content..."}
```

Comment: this creates the record but does not actually add it to the repository. `MyApp.Repo.insert post` will do that.